# Use of When and Then in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, jvm-languages

I have been seeing the use of "when" and "then" keyword in Groovy in several Groovy articles. One of them is [here](http://www.dzone.com/links/r/programming_with_groovy_trampoline_and_memoize.html). I searched for the Groovy Doc's but I couldn't find it. So whats the actual purposes of these keyword's? Similar to if/then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They aren't groovy keywords; they're actually constructs provided by some popular test frameworks.  It looks like [easyb](http://www.easyb.org/) and [spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) both use `when` and `then`.

In both cases, the test frameworks create a test specification DSL that looks human readable.

Answer (score 1):

`when` and `then`, among others, seem to be documented [here](https://code.google.com/p/spock/wiki/SpockBasics#Blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Technically the then, when and a few other constructs in Spock are good old labels (aka goto), which developers rarely use these days.
Spock uses them to allow developers to logically and visually separate different aspects of their tests - assumptions, constraints, statements or data.
The Spock compile-time AST transformations than use the labels to understand the structure of the test and do its magic.

Comment: A little confusing that the same label can be used multiple times in the same code block (at least... it is to me!)

Comment: Even in Java, the same label can be used multiple times in a row. There is no risk of ambiguity.